# Angular HttpClient calls are missing query string and Authorization header

Tags: asp.net, angular, http, iis, webforms

When Angular makes a GET call using HttpClient, the query parameters and Authorization header are missing on the request in our QA environment. When running Angular locally, pointed to the QA APIs, it sends them both as expected.

Here's how the query parameters are set:

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('schedulingOnly', schedulingOnly ? 'true' : 'false');
return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.getBaseUrl() + '/domain/getAll', { params });
```

Here's how the Authorization header is set (interceptor):

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (environment.useHttpMockRequestInterceptor) {
        return this.useMockData(request);
    } else {
        request = this.AddAuthenticationHeader(request);
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}

private AddAuthenticationHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access_token'))
    });

    return request;
}
```

Here's what Chrome dev tools is showing:
[image: Debugging tools]

That's all the basic information, but below is additional information about things I've tried without success.

- Is this a CORS issue? - While searching for others with this issue, I came across a lot of CORS issues. I do not believe that's the case here because Angular and the APIs are on the same domain and I can run Angular locally and hit the APIs no problem.
- Do query params get sent if I hardcode them into the url? - Yes. The following worked for the query params: return this.httpClient.get(this.getBaseUrl() + '/domain/getAll?schedulingOnly=true');
- Is this something wrong with the interceptor? - I don't believe so. Console.log() statements show all the expected points in code being hit. In fact, the request object after the interceptor adds the auth header shows it on there.
  [image]

I also tried setting directly without the interceptor, but no luck.

```
const obj = {
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access_token') },
  params: { 'schedulingOnly': schedulingOnly ? 'true' : 'false' }
};

return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.getBaseUrl() + '/domain/getAll', obj);
```

- There are no js errors in the console except the 401 error
- QA web server is IIS
- APIs are ASP.NET Core
- Angular is embedded within an ASP.NET Web Forms project (due to migrating that legacy code into Angular incrementally)

Comment: Here's an update: Taking the same Angular files embedded into ASP.NET Web Forms and running it directly (un-embedded) works fine. Seems like it must be something with ASP.NET Web Forms or IIS. Running locally with them embedded works fine, even with the Angular prod build.

Comment: Another update: I used XMLHttpRequest() instead of Angular's HttpClient to try and simplify things while troubleshooting and that DOES WORK. Obviously we're hoping to avoid that tho.                                
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             alert(this.responseText);
         }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", this.getBaseUrl() + '/domain/getAll', false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    xhttp.send();

Comment: Another update: Removing the ASP.NET Web Forms Master Page from the Angular.aspx (which serves as the Angular index.html file) DOES WORK. It seems like something within that ASP.NET Web Forms master page is interfering with Angular's HttpClient. I've searched the code for places in the js and C# code that would intercept an outgoing http request, but didn't see anything promising. Some libraries the master page loads are Telerik.Web.UI, jQuery, DefaultJS, and KendoJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that PrototypeJs was interfering with Angular. This led to the issue, but no warnings or errors, so it was just silently causing this issue. PrototypeJs is used in the containing ASP.NET Web Forms app that Angular is embedded into. The reason this was working locally, but not in QA is because I actually did have functionality to not load PrototypeJs if it was an Angular page, due to noticing other issues before, but that wasn't working in QA due to the site starting on a subpath, not directly on the host, so that functionality of not loading PrototypeJs wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the shorter version of adding header in your interceptor:

```
const request = request.clone({ 
  setHeaders: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access_token') } 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Interceptor

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (environment.useHttpMockRequestInterceptor) {
        return this.useMockData(request);
    } else {
        request = this.AddAuthenticationHeader(request);
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}

private AddAuthenticationHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>) {

   return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
      }
    });

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion though!